# Will installing Ubuntu 16.04 to an external hard drive touch the C: drive?

Tags: 16.04

I don't want ubuntu to touch any other hard drives in the process, im at the part of clicking install now or not.

Comment: In short, no. Not at all. **Unless you select Erase Windows**.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju Can you expand on your comment and make it an answer? Leave me a comment and I will give you an up vote, the answer is simple but correct.

Comment: It won't touch the Windows partition but if using UEFI then you'd better be clear on where you are installing the bootloader to. Typically here I'd install to the external drive though then it would have to be connected to boot up normally to either Windows or Ubuntu. If not on UEFI then I'd definitely install to the external

Comment: @pfeiffep OP said *external* drive.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju some machine has the capability to boot *external drives* ... I stand by my comment.  BTW you answer is spot on!

Comment: @pfeiffep I am confused — what were you saying as '100% incorrect'?

Comment: I am also curious why it asks where to put the boot loader at the bottom of the "something else" screen.  And i have installed Ubuntu on other systems before but now on one with as many drives as this once and it appears more complicated.

Comment: Thanks a lot i was assuming know but i wanted to be sure it like wouldnt overwrite the bootloader or something.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju your initial comment - I 100% mis-interpreted . Your were spot on there also. My apologies. If I can edit that comment I certainly will ... edit not available on the comment so I deleted it

Answer (score 2):

If, as you said, you are installing on an external hard drive, your Windows partitions shall not be disturbed. (Side note: In fact, it's *Windows* that messes up partitions)

Select *Something Else* at this screen:

[image]

You should be at a screen that looks something like this: (Details may be different, ignore them for now)

[image]

**Make sure** that you are installing on the external hard drive. Note its ID (the `/dev/sd×y` thing, in the *Device* column, where × is any letter and y is any number). Let's say that the ID is `/dev/sdb1` (**just** an example), then you'd

1. Select it on the list
2. Click *Change…*

Now, a dialog should pop up. In it

3. Check the *Format* checkbox
4. Select *Mount point* as `/`

An important thing would be to make sure that the *Device for boot loader installation:* is the same as the external drive's ID.

[image]

**NOTE:** If your computer uses UEFI instead of BIOS (i.e. any computer that came pre-loaded with Windows 8 or newer), then you will need to choose BIOS and then choose the Ubuntu hard disk to get into Ubuntu.

Comment: @MarkKirby Here.

Comment: In order to boot Ubuntu installed on an external drive with the boot loader on the external drive you will need to use a bios /uefi selector to boot so Ubuntu's MBR is accessed.

Comment: @pfeiffep Adding to answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing on an external hard drive, your Windows partitions *should* not be disturbed.

The most effective way of ensuring that there is no possibility that the  installation of Ubuntu on your external drive touches your C drive is to remove the SATA cable from the C drive during the install.